# Claims based authentication per entity

Tags: asp.net, authorization, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have a set of projects that multiple users can manage, I also have a set of claims that provide different access to the projects:

```
projectContentRead - ability to read project content
projectContentWrite - ability to modify project content
projectUserRead - ability to see what users are added to the project
projectUserWrite - ability to add users to the project
```

I want to be able to add these specific claims to a user based on the project, I have thought about adding a claim with the permission as the type and the projectId as the value but this doesn't seem right:

```
new Claim("projectContentRead", projectId)
new Claim("projectUserRead", projectId)
```

With this approach I can see the amount of claims the user can have could grow large quite quickly.

Is there a more standard way to solve the problem of having claims for a specific entity?

Comment: These are seperate projects. Consider to use an authentication server (like IdentityServer3 or 4). Register each project with a client/secret for external login and define scopes. Here's a link: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/index.html

Comment: @kiwijus Did you manage to find a solution?